# Ruby on Rails equivalent for Maven Archetypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, archetypes

Maven Archetypes are handy ways to get a project up and going in no time flat. Rails is kinda like an archetype in and of itself. However, I'm curious to know if there are any Rails equivalents for Maven Archetypes.

For example, I want to create an Archetype with full authentication already built in via Authlogic. With Maven Archetypes I would need to build a project with it already ready to go, create my archetype and start working back parameterizing things that should be parameterized. Then anyone can make a Rails project with Authlogic set up by filling out a few questions during the archetype generate command and boom! Fully functional Rails app with Authlogic built in.

Is there a Rails Equivalent? Are Generators expected to do this? Is this just not Rails-y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that rails app templates are the most similar thing to Maven Archetypes. http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3 is a good starting point to get an opinion about them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for [Modules and Mixins](http://www.innovationontherun.com/why-rubys-mixins-gives-rails-an-advantage-over-java-frameworks/)?

I'm not sure but [rails casts](http://railscasts.com/) might have something else to add.